# For every 3 unique ids group together and set groupid without using CASE Expression

Tags: sql, sql-server

Table `table_name`

| id |
| --- |
| 1 |
| 2 |
| 3 |
| 4 |
| 4 |
| 5 |
| 6 |
| 6 |
| 7 |
| 7 |
| 7 |
| 8 |
| 9 |
| 9 |
| 10 |

Following SQL will give me the answer [Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/a-IrXFQa) but I need to hardcode each case and I need to know the MAX(id) in the first place.

```
SELECT id,
CASE 
WHEN id > '0' AND id <= '3' THEN 1 
WHEN id > '3' AND id <= '6' THEN 2 
WHEN id > '6' AND id <= '9' THEN 3 
WHEN id > '9' AND id <= '12' THEN 4
END AS groupid
FROM table_name
```

How to improve it without me hardcode using the `CASE`. Since `id` column will continue increasing and it will runout of case sometime later.

(SQL Server 2014 - build v12.0.6108.1)

Result:

| id | groupid |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 |
| 2 | 1 |
| 3 | 1 |
| 4 | 2 |
| 4 | 2 |
| 5 | 2 |
| 6 | 2 |
| 6 | 2 |
| 7 | 3 |
| 7 | 3 |
| 7 | 3 |
| 8 | 3 |
| 9 | 3 |
| 9 | 3 |
| 10 | 4 |

Comment: what is the datatype of id

Comment: Simply `(id - 1) / 3 + 1`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT id, CEILING(id/3.0) AS groupid
FROM table_name
```

Comment: Would be great to also see some explanation in this answer rather than just pure code.